# Can MIDI Designer control other iPad apps?

Tags: midi, ipad

I installed MIDI Designer on my iPad, but I can't find any way to configure it to control another iPad app, such as Animoog or Samplewiz. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** I am the author of MIDI Designer. Also: at the time this question was asked, MIDI Designer did not present its own virtual MIDI ports. That feature has been added.

MIDI Designer can control other apps, even if the other apps do not present a Virtual MIDI Port. In addition, MIDI Designer allows you to selectively activate/deactivate virtual MIDI connections.

Video demonstrating virtual MIDI with MIDI Designer is here: